# Xamarin iOS, bind "Enable property" using MVVMCross

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am trying to enable the button in Xamarin iOS based on "HasChanges" property.

Currently, I am using

```
bindingSet.Bind(submitBtn).For(v => v.Enabled).To(vm => vm.HasChanges). TwoWay();
```

But it's not enabling the button if the "HasChanges" is true.
Can someone please point out the error in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind,

I got it. All I needed to do was raisePropertyChange event whenever "HasChanges" value was being updated.

Comment: `TwoWay` is default value for this particular binding so you can omit it. And in specific cases there is a default binding for a type. For example in your case you can bind button to command which implements `CanExecute` and that is all you need to make sure that button is bound and disabled when command cannot be executed. Just don't forget to `Command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged` when this condition changed.